# How to set Datepicker default index is string value

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to show datepicker default index value is string but I am not able to do that. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

I want to show picker like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UITextField` and add date picker as a Input vie. And set `PlaceHolder` as "Date" or any string you want.

Sample Code

```
UITextField TextInput = new UITextField();
            TextInput.Frame = new CGRect(40, 280, View.Frame.Width - 80, 40);

            TextInput.Placeholder = "Date";

            var picker = new UIDatePicker();

            TextInput.InputView = picker;
```

Comment: Thanks mayank, Can you please send me any sample code. I didn't get exactly what your saying.

Comment: Thank you very much mayank, but I am working on portable project, so it's very difficult to maintain like this in another platforms. Please suggest any idea for working in all plat forms.

Comment: There is no  direct way to do that in Forms. You will have to write custom renderer for each platform to do that.

Comment: If you have any idea, Can you please suggest any custom render's.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to do it in ViewCell. You can use similar idea with View

```
   public class TimePickerInCellPage : ContentPage
    {
        private ListView _listView;

        public TimePickerInCellPage()
        {
            _listView = new ListView
            {
                RowHeight = 80,
                SeparatorColor = Color.Blue,
                SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.Default
            };

            _listView.ItemsSource = new List<TaskTime>() {
                 new TaskTime { Id=1, StartTime=TimeSpan.FromHours(3) } ,
                 new TaskTime { Id=1, StartTime=TimeSpan.FromHours(5) } ,
                 new TaskTime { Id=1, StartTime=TimeSpan.FromHours(7) } ,
            }; 
            _listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyCell));

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Children = { _listView }
            };
        }

    }

    public class TaskTime
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Task { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    }

    class MyCell : ViewCell
    {
        private readonly DatePicker _myTimePicker;
        //private readonly TimePicker _myTimePicker;
        public MyCell()
        {
            //_myTimePicker = new TimePicker()
            _myTimePicker = new DatePicker()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
            };
            //_myTimePicker.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
            _myTimePicker.Format = "dd:MM:yy HH:mm:ss";

            _myTimePicker.SetBinding(TimePicker.TimeProperty, "StartTime");
            _myTimePicker.PropertyChanged += MyTimePicker_PropertyChanged;
            //_myTimePicker.Focused += _myTimePicker_Focused;

            var viewLayout = new StackLayout()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Padding = new Thickness(20),
                Children = { _myTimePicker }
            };
            View = viewLayout;
        }

        bool firstTimeSet; //set when initial binding happens
        //private void _myTimePicker_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    firstTimeSet=true;
        //}

        private void MyTimePicker_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (e.PropertyName == TimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName)
            if (e.PropertyName == DatePicker.DateProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                if (!firstTimeSet)
                    firstTimeSet = true;
                else
                {
                    int x = 0;
                    string s = _myTimePicker.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```